# How to return the type of a class based on a FileType

Tags: c#, generics, image-processing, aspose

I am working on a image processing processes. I am using Aspose image processor. I want to get related classes by image type. Such as, gif, png, jpeg, etc.

For instance, the following code block can be used to generate a png image. I would like to do it as generic and would like to use generic types instead of PngOptions and PngImage.

```
        PngOptions options = new();

        using (PngImage image = (PngImage)Image.Create(options, fileInformation.Width, fileInformation.Height))
        {
            Graphics graphic = new Graphics(image);
            graphic.Clear(Color.Green);
            // Draw line on image
            graphic.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Blue), 9, 9, 90, 90);

            // Resize image
            int newWidth = 400;
            image.ResizeWidthProportionally(newWidth, ResizeType.AdaptiveResample);

            // Crop the image to specified area
            AsponseRectangle area = new AsponseRectangle(10, 10, 200, 200);

            image.Crop(area);

            image.Save();
        }
```

Png Options is inherited from ImageOptionsBase, and PngImage is inherited from RasterCachedImage. I am trying to get which kind of options I should use based on File Type. You can see the following code. It returns an error that says "GifOptions is a type, which is not valid in the given context." I could not fully set the structure in my mind. I would be very happy if someone could give an idea.

```
     private Dictionary<ImageOptionsBase, RasterCachedImage> GetFileTypes(RequestFileType requestFileType)
    {
        switch (requestFileType)
        {
            case RequestFileType.Bmp:
                return new Dictionary<ImageOptionsBase, RasterCachedImage>() { BmpOptions, BmpImage };
            case RequestFileType.Gif:
                return new Dictionary<ImageOptionsBase, RasterCachedImage>() { GifOptions, GifImage };
            case RequestFileType.Dicom:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Djvu:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Dng:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Emf:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Jpeg:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Jpeg2000:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Pdg:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Png:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Apng:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Psd:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Svg:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Tiff:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Dib:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Eps:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.WebP:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Wmf:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Cdr:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Cmx:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Otg:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Pdf:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Html5Canvas:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Emz:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Wmz:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Tga:
                break;
            case RequestFileType.Svgz:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you are trying to achieve but '`GifOptions is a type, which is not valid in the given context.`' says that you are trying to use a type when something else is expected. In your case an object (not a class) is expected when you initialise the dictionary.

When you initalise a dictionary you need to give it objects to store not types of objects only.

Again, I'm not sure what objects you work with, but maybe the following line will help with understanding the problem. Please note the `new`.

```
return new Dictionary<ImageOptionsBase, RasterCachedImage>() { new BmpOptions(), ... };
```